# How to get the value of the highlighted item with react-select-plus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-select-plus](https://github.com/HubSpot/react-select-plus) and I'm trying to get the value of the highlighted item when I navigate between them by keyboard,

how can I make this work?

here's a sample of my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(); 
  }

  loadOptions(input, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(null, {
        options: [
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
        ], 
        complete: true
      });
    }, 500);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Async 
          loadOptions={this.loadOptions}  
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope you can help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out how it's possible to get the current highlighted item:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(); 
  }

  keyUp() {
    let item = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(document.getElementsByClassName('Select-option is-focused')[0]);
    console.log(item.textContent);
  }

  loadOptions(input, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(null, {
        options: [
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
        ], 
        complete: true
      });
    }, 500);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div tabIndex="0" onKeyUp={this.keyUp.bind(this)}>
        <Async 
          loadOptions={this.loadOptions}  
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to deal with `onInputKeyDown` ?

Comment: tried this already, `OnInputKeyDown` will get the value that was highlighted before you navigated to the other value. 
`onKeyUp` happen when the acton of the highlight ended and standing on the current value.